# Proof of inequality using AM-GM inequality generalisation

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c) \geq 8abc$

I need a full proof and an explanation. I've tried it, but I don't even know how to begin.

Comment: Hint: expand LHS and apply AM-GM.

Comment: Even simpler, use the AM-GM inequality on each term on the left.

Comment: Hint: $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$... do the same for the rest and multiply

Comment: Answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845607/how-to-establish-this-inequality-1-a1-b1-c-geq-8abc-for-abc-1/845616#845616

Answer (score 4):

Use: $x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}$

$$a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab} (1)$$
$$c+b\ge 2\sqrt{cb} (2)$$
$$a+c\ge 2\sqrt{ac} (3)$$

$$(1)\cdot (2)\cdot(3) \Rightarrow $$
$$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\ge 8\sqrt{a^2b^2c^2}=8abc$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$\frac { a+b }{ 2 } \ge \sqrt { ab } $$
$$ \frac { a+c }{ 2 } \ge \sqrt { ac } $$
$$\frac { c+b }{ 2 } \ge \sqrt { cb } $$
and multiple all