# Prove $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)≤\frac8{27}(x+y+z)^3$

Tags: inequality

The entire exercise was like
$$8xyz≤(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)≤\frac8{27}(x+y+z)^3\quad x,y,z>0$$ 
and I managed to solve (demonstrate) the first inequality (from the left) using
$$\frac{x+y}2≥\sqrt{xy}$$
but I can't solve the second one. I tried several ideas but I haven't succeeded.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: For future reference, the first inequality is treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845607/how-to-establish-this-inequality-1-a1-b1-c-geq-8abc-for-abc-1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** The arithmetic mean of $\frac{x+y}2$, $\frac{x+z}2$, $\frac{y+z}2$ is $\frac{x+y+z}{3}$, whereas the geometric mean is $\sqrt[3]{\frac{(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)}{8}}$

Comment: Thanks, I used your hint and demonstrated  the second equality.

Comment: I started from the fact that $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}≥\sqrt[3]{\frac {x+y+z}8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$P(x;y;z)=\frac{8}{27}(x+y+z)^3-(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$$
$P(1;1;1)\ge0; P(1;1;0)\ge0$ and $P(1;0;0)\ge0$
Then $$P(x;y;z)\ge0$$
Hence,
$$(x+y)(y+z)(x+z) ≤ \frac{8}{27}(x+y+z)^3$$